# How to reduce repetitive behaviour in a 3-year-old?

Tags: toddler, habits

My 3-year-old son doesn't cross legs while sitting down. He keeps his legs like (<>). He moves his toes and keeps his two hands below the mouth (as if it is so chill) whenever he is doing any task or when getting excited he has this habit from 8 months. How to reduce it? Now in this month he learnt another habit of keeping fingers in mouth as if he was biting his nails.

Comment: Hi Nilah.  Can you let us know why you're concerned about these behaviors?  Repetitive behavior is very common in children (and adults!), and when it's not disruptive to their life it's typically not something to be concerned about.  Can you explain why you're concerned?  Is this behavior disruptive to his day in some way, or is it leading to anything in particular that's problematic for you?  Thanks!

Comment: Its very odd and when he is playing with car he performs the action for every movement of bus.He is performing the movement of the hand by bitting the teeth with limited duration when performing any task.It is not nice to see that and so I asked.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some repetitive movements may be normal (what is normal, anyway?LOL), there are some that are generally considered socially unacceptable. Although I don't understand all of the movements you described, it sounds like you feel as if the repetitions come under the category of socially unacceptable. Perhaps he would benefit from some occupational therapy. Occupational therapists provide interventions to aid in more social participation, and treat repetitive behaviors. You haven't shared as to whether he is talking yet and if not, speech therapy might also be beneficial. An OT with some psychological background would probably be helpful, to determine if there are any behaviors that require other types of therapy.  Good luck!